# iOS: How can I get username/password out of keychain for function "isEqual"?

Tags: ios, keychain, autologin

I'd like to autologin the user when the user is logged in. the credentials are saved in keychain, but now i have to compare them..

how can I get them out for a comparison?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the [GenericKeychain](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/GenericKeychain/Introduction/Intro.html) classes made by Apple. This shows how to access the keychain securely.

**EDIT**

Take a look at this blog post: [Simple iPhone Keychain Access](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2010/3/29/simple-iphone-keychain-access.html).

Comment: Damn you looked up the link faster than me! :)

Comment: thank you guys, but I already know this code (didn't help me much). it does not explain how to make a string out of keychain data.

Comment: Take a look at the link i added!

Comment: Hmmm can't help you with that :( hope it was helpful!